# Who held the girl in the secret room?

Tags: 10-cloverfield-lane

Who held the girl in the secret room in *10 Cloverfield Lane*?

If Howard was too fat to go to there would not like it take the body beneath, and above could not open, there was only lock from the inside, then who was trapped in that room and who was he held?

Answer (score 3):

Howard kept "Megan" locked up in the secret room (before the attack ever happened). Howard kept referring to Megan as his daughter to Michelle and Emmet but we find out that Megan was not Howard's daughter but a local girl he had kidnapped and killed some time ago.

There was another entrance to the secret room with the air purifier where "Megan" was held near Michelle's room. Howard tries to open it when he initially finds out the purifier has stopped working-- it is a ceiling entrance that Howard tried to pull down. When Howard realized he could not get up there that way, he sends Michelle up through the vents. Howard also could have taken Megan through the outdoor opening where she wrote "help" if it was unlocked at that time.

Comment: I really wish I knew why I keep being downvoted for this.  The other answerer posted their answer nearly seven months after mine, with nearly the exact same answer as mine except they provided a link.

Comment: This happened me to also.. initially people starts judging answeres/questions then if I ask why down vote? then they realize and see what the content is really.. and they upvote it....

Answer (score 2):

In the film, there is a scene when Howard is trying to access a door to the ventilator room. That seems jammed, hence he sends Michelle through the duct.

ref : [10 Cloverfield Lane Explained](http://www.thisisbarry.com/single-post/2016/11/29/10-Cloverfield-Lane-2016-Movie-Plot-Ending-Explained)

> **Who is Megan, Brittany?**
>
> Howard seems to have also used his bunker to abduct a girl a couple of years ago. Now this is only speculation
> but there are sufficient clues that point to the abduction. Brittany
> is the name of the girl he (allegedly) abducts. She is someone who
> went missing a couple of years back. Howard carries a picture of
> Brittany and claims that it is his daughter Megan.
>
> When the
> ventilator shuts down, Michelle crawls over to the ventilation room
> and turns it back on. Michelle finds Brittany’s earring in the bunker
> and also sees “HELP” scratched onto one of the fiberglass doors. On
> talking to Emmett, it is revealed that the picture that Howard is
> carrying is not of his daughter Megan but a girl named Brittany.
> Emmett confirms that Brittany was in the same highschool as his
> younger sister. So looks like Howard has abducted Brittany after his
> family moves away (and after he loses his real daughter Megan).

Many years ago, it looks like Howard kidnapped and held the girl (Brittany) captive in his bunker.